# ng-animate not firing custom JavaScript Animations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, ng-animate

The issue is issue is with requireJS  and ngAnimate using custom JavaScript animations.
Mainly the setup and start methods are not called. I can confirm that the files are loaded via requireJS but the animations are not fired. I'm starting to think my code is incorrect despite the fact that i have followed all the instructions.
Can someone post an implementation with RequireJS? or point out my error?

```
define(['angular'],
function (angular) {
    var animations = angular.module('animations', []);
    animations.animation('js-animation', function () {
        return {
            setup: function (myElement){
                console.log('we are in here');
                myElement.hide();
                $('.unpublish, .good, .delete').fadeOut('slow');
            },
            start: function (myElement, done) {
              console.log('we are in the start');
            },
            cancel : function(element, done) {

                done();
            }
        }
    });
    return animations;
});
```

I would think that the way to execute my animation would be as follows

```
    <ul>
    <li ng-animate="{enter: 'js-animation'}" ng-repeat="gallery in galleries">
        {{ gallery.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Am I declaring the animation improperly or is there something wrong with this code?